# My question has disappeared :(

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

So I asked a question yesterday about how to do quantum mechanics with a Sturm-Liouville Schrödinger equation. Somehow it has disappeared completely :(

If I had to guess I might have accidentally deleted it in the app. I did some editing there and have pretty clumsy fingers. However I have deleted other things on purpose before and then I could just find them in the reputation notifications or elsewhere. I believe that also gave the option to undelete.

In this case the question seems to have disappeared completely though, so I'm not sure that accidental deleting was the reason. Can someone help me recover it?

Comment: It seems you accidentally deleted [it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342061/2451).

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks a lot!

Comment: @Qmechanic Answer & mark as status-completed?

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: Actually, I did but because of the short length, it was converted to a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you accidentally deleted [your question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342061/2451) 5 hours ago.

Update: OP has now undeleted his question.

Comment: And apparently it's been deleted again :/

Comment: Yes, deleted again by OP.

Comment: @Qmechanic kind of an old topic, but I have undeleted the question again. Apologies for the back an fourth, I had a request from my employer to remove the question due to overlap with our research. 3 years later this is no longer the case :) Thanks for your help in finding the question again.